# Typescript decorators as mixins?

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm writing a big application in Angular2. I have a base class that does this:

```
export abstract class ReactiveComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
    abstract ngOnInit(): void;
    protected _subscriptions: Rx.Subscription[] = [];
    private __viewInit = new Rx.Subject<void>();
    protected _viewInit: Rx.Observable<void> = this.__viewInit;
    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this._subscriptions)
            this._subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe());
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.__viewInit.complete();

    }
}
```

But some of my classes need to have other base classes, and I'm hitting the classic mixin/inheritance brick wall.

So I was thinking about turning this into a decorator, since Angular2 won't care where those methods came from, I can easily do a `constructor.prototype.ngOnDestroy = ...`

**Right?**

Which leaves me with 2 questions:

1. Do I have any way of letting the protected members "show up" in the decorated class so that I can write `this._subscriptions` in Typescript?
2. What if I want to add a `@ContentChildren(...) someStuff;` property via a mixin? How can I dynamically define a decorator on `constructor.prototype.someStuff`? Am I in the wrong ballpark for "traits" all together?

Answer (score 1):

(1) No, you probably can't enjoy both using mixins and having protected members/methods.
While the mixins are actual classes, you inherit them as interfaces:

```
class MixinA {
    public a(): void { console.log("A"); }
}

class MixinB {
    public b(): void { console.log("B"); }
}

class MyClass implements MixinA, MixinB {
    public a: () => void;
    public b: () => void;
}

applyMixins(MyClass, [MixinA, MixinB]);
```

Where the key word is **`implements`**.
As a general OO principle interfaces are public contracts and they don't deal with the actual implementation which is the realm of protected functionality.

(2) If I understand you correctly when you say `"dynamically define a decorator"` then yes, it's similar to the example for [Property Decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators) in the official docs, so you should be able to do something like (**untested**):

```
const numbersMetadataKey = Symbol("numbers");
type Producer = () => number;
type Reducer = (previous: number, current: number) => number;

function numbers(...props: Array<number | Producer>) {
    return Reflect.metadata(numbersMetadataKey, props);
}

function getNumbers(target: MyClass, propertyKey: string) {
    let arr: Array<number | Producer> = Reflect.getMetadata(numbersMetadataKey, target, propertyKey);
    return arr.map(item => typeof item === "number" ? item : item());
}

function numberFactory(min: number = 0, max: number = 100): number {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

class MyClass {
    @numbers(numberFactory(), numberFactory.bind(null, 50, 200))
    private reducer: Reducer;

    constructor(reducer: Reducer) {
        this.reducer = reducer;
    }

    reduce(): number {
        let numbers: number[] = getNumbers(this, "reducer");
        return numbers.reduce(this.reducer);
    }
}

new MyClass((previous, current) => previous + current).reduce();
new MyClass((previous, current) => previous * current).reduce();
```

I just want to add that sometimes multiple inheritance is required and unavoidable, if supported at all (here it's implemented with mixins) but in other times the need for it just points to an inadequate design.

Comment: Yeah, I don't actually want multiple inheritance, I want "Traits" or "AOP" or whatever we're calling the cool magic these days

Comment: Mixins are traits, and that's how you achieve multiple inheritance in typescript. My point was that while this is the best way to go sometimes, in other cases you can change your design and use normal inheritance which is easier in most cases. In any case I showed how you can use mixins to do what you're after

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find a way without the need for those protected members... The rest of my needs are fully satisfied by the mixins. As for (2), I might have more questions once I fully understood what your example does. :)